# How to know current Location in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mapkit, core-location

I am new to iphone App development, I Need code Current Location of the user. I want show his Location in My App using map Kit. Please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer the apple's document for this [CLLocationmanager class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction) showCurrentLocation{  
    MKCoordinateRegion region;  
    MKCoordinateSpan span;    
    span.latitudeDelta=0.007;  
    span.longitudeDelta=0.007;  
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [[[mapview userLocation] location] coordinate];  
    //NSLog(@"Location found from Map: %f %f",location.latitude,location.longitude);  

    region.span=span;  
    region.center=location;  


    [mapview setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
    [mapview regionThatFits:region];    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the map view to show the user's location (it's not on by default). Add this to the **viewDidLoad**:

```
[mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
```

Note that in the simulator, the **user location** is always Cupertino, CA so you might not see it depending on the map's current center and zoom.

Comment: Do You Have Exact Example? Please give me the link